# tinymce get HTML code when postback

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, postback

I have the tinymce -control as a WYSIWYG-Editior in my asp.net page.

When I have e.g. a Text in Bold, after the Postback it is shown as

```
 "<p><strong>asd</strong></p>"
```

in the textarea instead of the bolded text.

Any ideas?

My code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "simple",
        encoding: "xml"
    });
</script>


<textarea runat="server" id="txtareaTextActivity" name="content" cols="48" rows="5">  </textarea>
```

Comment: Could you paste the javascript code and the textarea you are adding tinymce to?

Comment: Found the same error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748786/asp-net-4-0-with-tinymce-and-xml-encoding-re-encodes-content-on-postback

Comment: Do you use an UpdatePanel for the postback? If so the tinyMCE is not initialized for the "updated" textarea.

Comment: Not to disrespect you but are you using an up to date version of tinyMCE? http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=15407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of search, there is no way of this, it's an unsolved bug until now.
So I had to switch to another WYSIWYG-Editor.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem. But fixed it by decoding the `textarea` text each time in page load in c# as below:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          // Some stuff
        }
        txtDescription.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txtDescription.Text);
    }
```

I'm using `encoding: "xml"` in tinymce init function. .net version `4.5.1`.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for solving your problem:

> `TextAreaID.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("<p>hello</p>");`

I found it in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8029637/1509986

If you get some security errors you can use

```
validateRequest="false"
```

in your page.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the editor control in placed within Update Panel.
Try to remove update panel and check. It worked for me.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you for this big big help. It actually worked for me. It has really solved a lot of my code problems. Eventually You are a God to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your js code to the ScriptManager. Worked for me.

```
string script = "alert('something')";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanelSend, typeof(UpdatePanel), "jscript", script, true);
```

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6725

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
in TinyMCE Configuration use

```
encoding: "xml",
```

Step 2: in Java Script
after init the TinyMCE use this code, where 'textarea.RichText' is the class selector for the text area

```
tinymce.init(TMCEconfig);

 // Fix Html Decodeing
    $('textarea.RichText').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var x = $this.text();
            $this.html(x)
    });
```

Step 3 : in Server code, when setting the value of the text area , decode the text first
For example in  ASP.net use

```
textarea.text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem.for fix it you mast add script code for element create post back . my button create post back,I add it OnClientClick() :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbnSave" OnClick="lbnSave_Click" ToolTip="Add New" OnClientClick="dotim()"
                            runat="server">save</asp:LinkButton>
```

and script is:

```
function dotim() {
       tinyMCE.triggerSave();
      } // this is my attempt at a fix
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the init function and set encoding to an empty string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "simple",
        encoding: ""
    });
</script>
```

This is default setting, and worked in my case. See documentation on this page http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:encoding

Comment: Setting encoding  to "" causes  Error: "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client "