# TinyMce page reload after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I use tinymce in xml mode and convert the xml back server-side with the `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` function. All works well.

However, when i decide to keep that page in edit mode, making tinymce show before and after postback tinymce shows the contents with html tags instead of interpreting as html after postback.

Now you might think that i'm sending the xml encoded text back to the browser after postback, but i checked and **i'm sending exactly the same text as i would on a refresh of the page**.

So when i refresh the page the text is shown correctly.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this?

Comment: See my answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34100978/1201322

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your tinymce init is missing the following line

```
encoding: "xml",
```

This is necessary for ASP.NET.

**EDIT**: looks like i missed that part.
You may try this in your init

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onPostProcess.add(function(ed, o) {
    o.content = ed.dom.encode(o.content);
    });
},
```

If this does not help i suggest you have a closer look into [the tinymce forum](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/search.php).

Comment: I started my question by writing i use tinymce in xml mode, so my tinymce.init has the line you're suggesting.

Comment: No, that's not it either. It looks like mvc is doing some encoding. I send a string with regular html to the page and the page source shows encoded html in the <textarea>. Strange thing is that either case, postback or not, i send the same string.